# Angular 5: Cant not find csv file

Tags: angular

I am having problems with Angular 5. As module to recovder **csv** I am using Papa.parse version 4 module. I am debugging using Chrome.

I have the next directory structure:

[image]

Each directory inside assets/data has one file: **data.csv**.

Papa.parse code is:

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { PapaParseModule } from 'ngx-papaparse';

import { PapaParseService } from 'ngx-papaparse';

import { Capcaleres } from "../assets/models/Capcaleres.Model";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private csvData: any[] = [];
    private Papa: any = null;

    constructor(private http: Http, private papa: PapaParseService) {
        this.Papa = papa;
    }


    public cargarFitxer(obj: any): any
    {

        debugger;

        // preparo la url
        var url: string = "../../assets/assets/{0}/{1}/data.csv";
        var clase: any = obj;
        var nomClase: string = clase.constructor.name.toLowerCase();
        var manteniments: string[] = [
            "capcaleres",
            "idiomes",
            "llenguatgesprogramacio",
            "nivells",
            "posicions",
            "tipusempresa"
        ];


        var tipus = (manteniments.find(x => x === nomClase)) ? "manteniments" : "llogica";

        url = url.replace("{0}", tipus);
        url = url.replace("{1}", nomClase);

        debugger;
        // recullo la informació.


        this.Papa.parse(url, {
            worker: false,
            download: true,

            complete: function () {
                console.log("All done!");
                debugger;
            }
        });

    }  
}
```

where the data.service.ts is in app directory level.

My angular-cli.json file is:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "admin-angular"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "data.csv"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../src/assets/scss/style.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/pace-js/pace.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

I don't have compilation errors:

[image]

In chrome the error is 404 file not found

[image]

What is wrong? I don't know what to do which Angular can recognize my csv and Papa.parse can work it.

Is it security level maybe of directories like IIS?

the url file I execute alone and the url is recognized without problems. What do I have to add?

Best Regards

Comment: In the image of your directory structure it looks like the filename is `data..csv` (notice the second dot). Does the actual filename have one or two dots?

Comment: oh my god, it was that, here we have an expression, two eyes better than one. thx, set as answer pls

Answer (score 0):

Thx Simon K.

two eyes much better than one data..csv was wrong